# Solspace Freeform Subject Line

Tags: solspace

I want to change the subject line so that instead of reading "Someone has filled out form: Form Name" I can use a shorter value like "Form Name." Where can I do this in Freeform?

---

I didn't know about the notifications template tab. It lets you specify a subject. Problem solved.

Godaddy requires short subject lines.

Comment: Your update to this question came only seconds after I posted my answer. That's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing is to set up a custom notification in the Freeform control panel and then in your form's settings assign that custom notification to your form.

But if you really want to edit the default notification's subject you'll have to edit Freeform's language file. Open up `third_party/freeform/language/english/freeform_lang.php` and search for `default_notification_subject` (it's around line 1338 in my copy of Freeform).

You'd edit it to look like

```
'default_notification_subject' =>
"{form_label}",
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the notification template for the particular form. This is available within the freeform module CP.